# Chaining Activerecord functions in a chainable activerecord function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm attempting to make a reusable library based off jquery-bootgrid.

When jquery-bootgrid makes a request for more data - pagination, search, what have you, the request is something like

http://localhost/controller/index.json?current=1&rowCount=30&searchPhrase=&_=1478278657109

and my action currently looks something like

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json do

            #:searchPhrase => :where et al
            some_helper_function_to_format(params) 

            @ar_objects = ArObject
                .where("some_extra_filtering IS true")
                .where(params[:where])
                .limit(params[:rowCount])
                .offset(params[:offset])
                .order(params[:sort])
        end
    end
end
```

I'd much prefer it to look like

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json do
            @ar_objects = ArObject
                .where("some_extra_filtering IS true")
                .jquery_bootgrid_options(params)
        end
    end
end
```

...jquery_bootgrid_options() would hide those standard where/limit/offset/order options, and return a relation ready for the view. Ideally, it's also populate a @object_count for the view before adding in limit/offset/order details - A jquery-bootgrid thing.

http://craftingruby.com/posts/2015/06/29/query-objects-through-scopes.html looked interesting, put trying to shoehorn params into the pattern (at least in rails 3.2.8) is seemingly impossible.

Should this be implemented as something in lib/? as an ActiveSupport::Concern?

How to I properly chain the first where()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think an ActiveSupport::Concern

As to how you create/populate @object_count in the controller instance, you can do this in the call provided you pass the controller instance

```
@ar_objects = ArObject.where("some_extra_filtering IS true")
                .jquery_bootgrid_options(self, params)
```

Then to set the instance variable in the controller...

```
module BootgridExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def jquery_bootgrid_options(controller, params={})
      # various stuff to create query_result
      controller.instance_variable_set(:@object_count, query_result.count) 
      return query_result
    end
  end
end
```

this will "automagically" create @object_count in your controller method.

Comment: Had to put parts before and after controller.instance_variable_set to get the right expected number, but seems to be working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a class method instead.

```
class ArObject
  def self.jquery_bootgrid_options(params={})
    where(params[:where])
    .limit(params[:rowCount])
    .offset(params[:offset])
    .order(params[:sort])
  end
end
```

Then just chain it in the controller like you did.

```
@ar_objects = ArObject
                .where("some_extra_filtering IS true")
                .jquery_bootgrid_options(params)
```